# How do I match either a path or a tt in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm building what I thought was a fairly simple macro in Rust to take in an arbitrary list of arguments (`str` or `ansi_term::Style` objects).

My macro looks like this:

```
macro_rules! test_macro {
    ( $( $x: tt ),* ) => (
        $(
            print!("{} ", $x);
        )*
        println!();
    )
}
```

For a minimum working example, I also defined a module and a function:

```
mod foo {
    pub fn test() -> &'static str {
        "doesn't"
    }
}

fn test() -> &'static str {
    "doesn't"
}
```

The macro works with simple invocations, such as

```
test_macro!("it", "works");
```

but if I try anything more complex, I get compiler errors:

```
fn test() -> &'static str {
    "doesn't"
}
test_macro!("it", test(), "work");
```

results in

```
error: no rules expected the token `(`
   |
24 |     test_macro!("it", test(), "work");
   |                           ^
   |                           |
   |                           help: missing comma here
```

and

```
test_macro!("it", foo::test(), "work");
```

results in

```
error: no rules expected the token `::`
   |
25 |     test_macro!("it", foo::test(), "work");
   |                          ^^
```

[Rust Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75c6690db962138e2608498c02173554).

This is my first time playing with Rust macros, so I may be missing something else.

Comment: FYI: `test_macro!("it", (foo::test()), "work");` is accepted.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `expr` rather than `tt`?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in your logic. As [mcarton noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745030/how-do-i-match-either-a-path-or-a-tt-in-a-macro#comment94350030_53745030), your macro should be `( $( $x: expr ),* )` not `( $( $x: tt ),* )`. That is, use expressions instead of token trees.

The way you are using your macro to print things won't work on some possible values that are present in token trees. I'm fairly certain you can't call `print!("{}", std::os)` which your macro would possibly allow.